# Casting char to float in embedded C

Tags: c, embedded

I am reading a 10-bit [A/D converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) on a [PIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontroller) microcontroller and want to average that value over several thousand calls and have the average end up as a char again. The returned value is a 16 bit char.

I want to do something like:

```
float f = 0.0;

for (int i=0; i<5000; i++) {
    n = readADC(); // Returns a char, 0->1023
    f = f + (float)n;
}

f = f / 5000.0;
n = (char)f;
// Send n somewhere as the final char which is a mean of 5000 calls to the ADC.
```

I am getting strange values back as if I'm not casting properly. How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that char is 16 bits? Seems very unlikely for ancient PIC. And why are you using the completely unsuitable char type to store 16 bit unsigned integer values?

Comment: I'd use fixed point math here, with a 32 bit accumulator.

Comment: `char` is definitely 8 bits.

Comment: If your compiler supports it (I'm not sure if MPLAB does), I would suggest using specified-width types from `stdint.h`. These are the `uint8_t, int8_t, ..., uint32_t, int32_t` types. If MPLAB doesn't support it, then you can probably find a third-party header that provides the proper `typedef`s for each PIC part. It just makes it explicit in the type what range of values will be valid.

Comment: my mistake, n is an unsigned short (16 bits), not a char

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a reading of max 1023 (10 bits) and want to average that 5000 times (~13 bits) then it should be pretty clear that a 16-bit accumulator for the averaging is (far) too small.

If the input is stuck at 1023, the sum after 5000 additions will be 5000 * 1023 = 5115000, which clearly does not fit in a 16-bit variable. Not even an `unsigned` one, which will max out at 65535, more than 78 *times* too little.

Use `uint32_t` for the accumulator sum.

Also consider averaging either 4096 or 8192 values, so the division can be done by shifting right either 12 or 13 bits.

Comment: He's using a `float` as an accumulator, which is fine (if a little inefficient) - the problem is that he is only using a `char` to read the ADC values and to store the final averaged result. (Although we now learn that `n` is `unsigned short`, not `char` after all.)

Comment: A float may not be "fine" for a number of reasons.  It takes a lot of code and a lot of time to perform floating-point on a PIC.  32 bit integer arithmetic code will be smaller and faster.  Single precision FP is good for 6 only decimal singifivant digits of precision, and the maximum sum possible has 7 significant digits.

Comment: yes, float as accumulator is over the top - i should use a normal 32 bit int as suggested - i like the shift for division idea.  unsigned int i;unsigned short j;(use i as accumulator over 4096 calls i = i + adc_unsigned_short_value);j=i>>12 ; is this correct to divide by 4096 and put into the 16 bit unsigned int?

Answer (score 1):

Since `char` is typically only 8 bits you may well get a bad value if your input data is > 127. Change `n` to `unsigned short` and change:

```
n=(char)f;
```

to:

```
n=(unsigned short)f;
```

Comment: thanks - will (short) cast to a signed or unsigned short?  I need an unsigned short - my mistake in calling it a char.

Comment: If it's only a 10 bit value then it makes no difference, but feel free to use unsigned short.

Comment: @user2633388  As Paul indicates, it was improper casting that caused your original problem. But you don't need to cast at all if `n` is already an `unsigned short`.

Answer (score 1):

This cast has no effect; when you use `+` on a `float` and a `char`, the integer value of the `char` is converted to be the closest `float` value.  C has implicit conversion between these two types.

For example:

```
 char ch = -5;
 float f = ch;  // f is now -5.0 (or the closest representable value to that)
```

When you write `n=(char)f;`: `f` is truncated towards zero, e.g.:

```
float f = -44.3;
char ch = f;    // ch is now -44
```

However, if this value is outside of the range of `char`, there is a problem. The behaviour is *implementation-defined* which means your compiler may do whatever it likes, but it must document that.  To be safe, you should check something like:

```
if ( f < CHAR_MIN || f > CHAR_MAX )
    ch = 0;   // and maybe output a message
else
    ch = f;
```

Regarding your claim about 16-bit chars: Systems with 16-bit chars do exist however they are very specialized, this is why some people are doubting the claim.

To verify this , examine `CHAR_BIT` defined in `limits.h`. Alternatively (if your implementation does not provide `CHAR_BIT`, `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX`, which is non-conforming btw) do this:

```
unsigned int u = (unsigned char)-1;
```

and output the value of `u` somehow, or perform a test on it. If you get 255 then it is 8-bit; if you get 65535 then it is 16-bit.